# Join two tables (with calculation)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Let's say I have these two tables in MySQL:

## 1. table_name

```
name
------
Max     
John
Sarah
Peter
```

## 2. table_money

```
name   | amount     | month
-------------------------------
Max    | 100        | January
Sarah  | 90         | January
Max    | 100        | February
Sarah  | 90         | February
Peter  | 90         | February
```

How has the SQL query to look, so that I can get a table like this:

```
name  | total (amount * #month)
-------------------------------
Max   | 200
Sarah | 180
Peter | 90
```

Comment: it would have a select, a from, a join and mathematical caluclation for the total. Now honestly, did you try anything yet or do you just want us to do it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using group by keyword

```
SELECT table_name.name,sum(table_money.amount) as total
FROM table_name JOIN table_money
on table_name.name = table_money.name
GROUP BY table_money.name
```

Hope this works

Comment: Okay. sorry, I'm new here.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
SELECT name,sum(amount) Total 
FROM table_money 
GROUP BY name
```